# Make it mandatory for moderators to give reason for deleting a VALID, NON-spam/abusive/offensive answer

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer, moderators

I feel when a moderator deletes an answer that someone worked hard to find the solution to and posts it, it is basic courtesy to let the answerer know why their time and effort have been nullified. *Especially*, when the answer is ***not*** spam or abusive or offensive.

Let me explain where I am coming from:

I had a problem with [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) and a [Jupyter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Jupyter#Jupyter_Notebook) plugin.
I searched for solutions on GitHub [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7161) and Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71206490/15065496).

The Stack Overflow question referred to above did not have images explaining the issue, and it wasn't very clear either. So, I posted my own questions on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73798728/15065496) and on GitHub [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/11423).

There weren't any answers for over two days, during which I was still actively trying to solve the issue myself.

I finally solved the issue myself and posted the answer in all above mentioned locations, including on my own question ([my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73827007/15065496)), so that anyone having the same niche problem will find the solution.

According to Stack Overflow [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer):

> Yes! Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions.
>
> [...]
>
> it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.

However, a moderator, deleted my answer on my own question without an explanation. I took two days to solve by myself because nobody else could find a working solution.

I looked for any explanation he might have provided, there was none. I tried to flag my answer for undeletion but it is not possible. I have tried to comment on my own answer to get the moderator's attention to ask for clarification on why he deleted my answer, but that is not possible. I have tried to ask the moderator directly, but that is not possible.

So, as a last resort, I am posting on the Meta site.

Comment: Since a moderator should only delete content as spam *when they are convinced it is spam*, there are no deletions that the moderator feels is wrong. That means you are asking them not to justify each "VALID, NON-spam/abusive/offensive answer" deletion but *each and every* single deletion. How are moderators supposed to handle this volume of extra work?

Comment: To be clear: Is this supposed to be about the *specific* deleted answer, asking for clarification for the *specific* deletion? Or is this about *general* policy, asking for clarification of *every* deletion? The title and parts of body seem to disagree, with quite a bit of ranting thrown in for good measure.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, sorry for the ranting :D. It is just very frustrating when your effort is just thrown away. 
I say if the answer(any answer in general) is NOT SPAM, but a duplicate of another answer maybe(POSTED BY THE SAME PERSON (basically me answering multiple questions properly, without SPAM/ABUSE/OFFENSIVE content)), then the moderators must provide sufficient reason to do so.

Comment: Please stop with the SHOUTING. It is very annoying to read and comes across as aggressive.

Comment: @ChandradharKoneti:  I'm confused as to your assertion that moderators must provide "sufficient" reason.  While yes, mods are human and can err on occasion, if it's the case that a deletion was perfectly in-line with policy, you'd still be left without the resolution of your answer being undeleted.  So...what would be the point of asking for the mods to explain themselves when you could just come to Meta (as you've done) to ask for clarification on this specific case (which you've done)?  Mods don't need to get involved unless they dun goof'd, and they did well here.

Comment: "*It is just very frustrating when your effort is just thrown away.*" it wasn't. Let's be honest here - *one* of the two identical answers you posted was deleted. The other remains. The effort you've put in is still public, just not duplicated.

Comment: @ChandradharKoneti But duplicating content needlessly *is* spamming the site. It may be a specific kind of spam but it is still spam. As far as I can tell from what I have seen, it is a rather common kind of spam – so again, if moderators have to justify each such deletion how are they supposed to handle this volume of extra work?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, sorry for caps. I use it for **emphasis**, not shouting.

Comment: @ChandradharKoneti please do not do it, it is generally considered as shouting in many English speaking countries and also considered to be a rude way of addressing someone.

Comment: If you want to use emphasise use **bold** or *italics*, don't use CAPITALS, which as mentioned come across as shouting. Also use emphasis *sparingly*, don't put entire paragraphs in bold/italics like you did in your [original revision](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/420533/1); if you feel that the entire paragraph needs emphasis it's likely none of it does.

Comment: Okay. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: We should do this as soon as we make it mandatory for users to give a reason for re-posting an UNHELPFUL DUPLICATE answer to multiple questions. I feel when users do this after moderators have been working so hard to keep the site clean, accessible, and information easy to find, it really violates basic courtesy. *Especially* when the Help Center, detailing how to post a good answer and what types of behavior is expected from users, is so easy to find. (Also, there's a link to https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers right underneath the deleted answer, right?)

Comment: What is up with using underscore instead of space? If you are afraid of linebreaks, then the HTML [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space), `&nbsp;`, is supported in [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown).

Comment: Without the context, *this* question reads as if adding yet another answer to old highly active Stack Overflow questions which already have 30 or more answers (at least that was my expectation when I started reading it). But it is actually about a ***self-answered question*** without any answers from others, a very different scenario. Perhaps make that clearer? (But ****** ***without*** ***** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now)

Comment: Side note: [Crossposting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossposting) (posting the same content at the same time), even if to different sites, is generally frowned upon (it was posted to Stack Overflow and GitHub ***the same day***). It can be considered a form of spamming.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The *only* time a moderator would do something like this is if [you've posted the ***exact same answer*** somewhere else on the site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73826994/1079354).  They get an automated flag for answers like that, and they're unceremoniously handled in that fashion.

In that workflow, it's preferable for you to flag the question as a duplicate rather than duplicate your answer.

Comment: Than you VERY MUCH for the clarification.

I have actually mentioned the 2 year old question in my question and have referred to it too.

Comment: How do I mark as duplicate my own question?? And what if MY question has MORE CLARITY than the old question??

Comment: Where are you getting "two-year old question" from?  The one you linked to on Stack Overflow was from February and then September.

Comment: But besides that @ChandradharKoneti, if the question you were going to ask would be answered in the same way you would've answered it on a post from February, then...the post from February would be the dupe target.  It might've been best to not post a new question about it at all if the answer is the exact same, honestly.

Comment: Sorry, the GITHUB thing is a year old, the SO thing was 7 months old. There was something else that was 2 years old that I I came across when researching my problem.

Comment: @ChandradharKoneti:  Oh, I don't care about the GitHub post.  That's not on Stack Overflow so its timeline is orthogonal to this discussion.

Comment: Honestly, The reason I posted the answer on all 4 places is coz SEARCHING for my problem itself was very difficult. Search engines were giving me results about how to change VS code background colour, how to change cell background colour and other stuff when I neededd to change OUTPUT cell background. So, I posted the answer everywhere in case anyone else searching for the same issue finds it, they will be happy.

Comment: @ChandradharKoneti:  We have the duplicates system to help with that issue.  On Stack Overflow at least, it's really...frustrating, shall we say...to have information duplicated in multiple places.  So, if one question can be answered in the same way as another, we close that question as a duplicate, so the information is in one place and is overall *easier* to find.  You didn't know that so you're getting a slap on the wrist, really, and you've had a chance to come to Meta to learn about it.  All's well that ends well here, I believe.

Comment: @ChandradharKoneti Bottom line: this has nothing to do with you answering your own question; it has everything to do with duplicating content. Posting the exact same answer on multiple questions is not allowed under any circumstances and it serves no good. If you thought the old question is difficult to find, you may edit it to make it more search-friendly. If you thought it was unclear, you may post your own self-answered (more clear) question and it might be used as a dupe target of the old question at some point. The one thing you did wrong is posting the same answer to both questions.

Comment: Okay. I understand why this was done. But Is there an option to merge questions which are duplicate. Since I would like to merge my more detailed question with his older question since he posted first. I want to upload my images to his question so that it is easier for future users to know the problem. I want to merge into his question and then delete/mark as duplicate my question.

@41686d6564standsw.Palestine: Thank you. It was helpful.

Comment: @ChandradharKoneti Wait until your answer gets an upvote or gets accepted by the OP and then your question can be closed as a duplicate of the other one. It's unlikely that they will be merged, but if closed as duplicate, people finding your question will be redirected to the other one where they can find your answer. In that case, you probably shouldn't delete the question so that it can serve as a signpost.